# iPhone Properties Issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am trying to make sure I am following correct memory management in my current application.  I have two questions though.

(1) Should I release [self.myString release] in dealloc()?  If not when will this get released?

(2) Should I set _myString = nil in the viewDidUnload()?

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    NSString *_myString;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *myString;

@end


@implementation ViewController

@synthesize myString = _myString;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Hello World"];

    NSLog(@"%@", self.myString);
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    self.myString = nil;
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [_myString release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Comment: I highly recommend you switch to ARC (Automatic Reference Counting) once this feature is enabled the compiler releases everything for you, eliminating the need to release anything yourself.

Comment: This is not an option, but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Hey MDT! How can ARC be made compatible with iOS<5.0 devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine. There is no need to do anything else.

> (1) Should I release [self.myString release] in dealloc()? If not when will this get released?

`self.myString` returns the same object as `_myString`. Since you already do `[_myString release]` once, you should not release it again.

> (2) Should I set _myString = nil in the viewDidUnload()?

Same situation. Your `self.myString = nil` already releases `_myString` and sets it to nil. There is no need to do it again.

You seem to be thinking that there are two separate objects, `_myString` and `self.myString`. That is not the case. All that `@synthesize myString = _myString` does is create two accessor methods, which are effectively the same as:

```
- (NSString*)myString { return _myString; }

- (void)setMyString:(NSString*)newValue
{
    if (newValue != _myString) {
        [_myString release];
        _myString = [newValue retain];
    }
}
```

Also, `x = self.myString` is the same as `x = [self myString]`, and `self.myString = x` is the same as `[self setMyString:x]`.

Comment: Is it better practice to release one over the other [self.myString release] or [_myString release] in the dealloc method, or since they both do the same it doesn't matter?

Comment: It's better to do `[_myString release]`. It's possible that, in a subclass of your object, somebody implemented an override of `-myString` or `-setMyString:` with different behavior. Doing `[self.myString release]` or `self.myString = nil` would call those overrides after the subclass's `-dealloc` had happened, which would be unexpected. It's unlikely, but why risk it?

Comment: Thanks a lot, that cleared it up for me.

Answer (score 0):

For every `alloc` there should be a `release`, unless object is autoreleased. Looking at documentation for `initWithString` it does not look like it is autoreleased, so this is ok.

`self.myString = nil;` is a safe practice, yes. This way, you won't accidentally assign a value to `myString` you don't want to see